# need to extract contents only from the html dom elements

Tags: java, html, string, dom, text-extraction

I need to extract the contents from the html elements like `<div>some text</div>`
In this element "some text" only i want in the output without any angle brackets

for example

```
LineNo:1<HTML>
LineNo:2<HEAD>
LineNo:3<TITLE>Your Title Here</TITLE>
LineNo:4</HEAD>
LineNo:5  <body>
LineNo:6  Bodycontent Start
LineNo:7    <div>
LineNo:8      div content start.
LineNo:9        <div> 
LineNo:10          subdiv content
LineNo:11        </div>
LineNo:12      div content end
LineNo:13    </div>
LineNo:14     body content end
LineNo:15  </body>
LineNo:16</HTML>
```

I need output like :
start line number is the line number of the tag opening
and the content is the content of that element only not including the content of the child elements.

start line number : 3, content : Your Title Here content 
start line number : 5, content : Bodycontent Start body content end
start line number : 7, content : div content start.  div content end
start line number : 9, content :  subdiv content

thanks

Comment: Have a look to `jsoup` : http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll` together with the regular expression `<[^<]+>` and replace with empty String.

```
String myStr = ...;
String myStrExtracted = myStr.replaceAll("<[^<]+>", "");
```